# Use Returned Range From Function

Tags: excel, vba

Follow up question to this:

[VBA - Using Current Selection As Range Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783257/vba-using-current-selection-as-range-object)

I have a sub (below) which is intended to copy the rows of data from the source sheet **(Run Results)** to the target sheet **(Failed)** based on the there being values in column F (Header name is Failure Type). The idea is that if *column F* contains any values found in my array `myFType`, then the entire row should be copied to the target sheet.

So, I can get this to work if I specify the Column explicitly (Column F) but I am trying not to do this and instead I use my function to locate the header then identify the range up to the last row of data and then make use of the range.

And this brings me to my query - How can I rewrite a line of this: `Range("E3:E" & lngLastRow & i)` to this: `Range(find_Header("Failure Type", "Copy") & i)` or even this `Range(find_Header("Failure Type", "Copy"))`

Because as it is, I am returning a range (or so I think) from my function, but from what I can tell it's not correct.

Writing out the line like this: `Range(find_Header("Failure Type", "Copy") & i)` gives me an error, but writing it like this: `Range(find_Header("Failure Type", "Copy").Address & i)` does not.

BUT, when I look at the "range" it shows me a ridiculous range of like +-8000 rows, and I only have 85 rows of data.. So this makes me think it's not working correctly. The catch is, if I select the range found, it selects the correct amount of rows (85).

This whole working with ranges is REALLY confusing me and all I am trying to achieve is copy a row by finding the header and based on the values in the column under that header.

In the Sub below, I have commented two sections where I need to "make use" of the range I return from my function.

**Here is the sub:**

```
Sub Copy()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim i As Long, J As Long, K As Long, x As Long, count As Long
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim element As Variant, myFType As Variant, myEnv As Variant, myDefects As Variant

    myFType = Array("F1", "F2", "F3")
    myEnv = Array("Env1", "Env2")
    myDefects = Array("New", "Existing")

    Set y = Workbooks("Template.xlsm")

    Set ws1 = y.Sheets("Run Results")
    Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Failed")

    i = Worksheets("Run Results").UsedRange.Rows.count
    J = Worksheets("Failed").UsedRange.Rows.count

    count = 3

    If J = 1 Then

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Failed").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0

    End If

    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    '************ 

    'This is where I would like to call the function to get the range
    'I want to change the line from: 
    'Range("E3:E" & lngLastRow & i) --> Range(find_Header("Failure Type", "Copy") & i)

    '************ 

    Set xRg = Worksheets("Run Results").Range("E3:E" & lngLastRow & i)

    'On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each element In myFType

        For K = 1 To xRg.count

            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = element Then

                myLRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & myLRow)

                J = J + 1

            End If

        Next

        ws2.Activate

        With ws2

            '************ 

            'This is where I would like to call the function to get the range
            'I want to change the line from: 
            'Range("E" & Rows.count) --> Range(find_Header("Failure Type", "Copy") & Rows.count)
            'AND
            'Range("E3:E" & x) --> Range(find_Header("Failure Type", "Copy") & x)

            '************ 

            x = Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

            Range("K" & count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E3:E" & x), element)

            count = count + 1

        End With

    Next element

    count = 8

    count = 12

    ws2.Columns("B:K").AutoFit

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Here is the function:**

```
Function find_Header(header As String, fType As String) As Range

    Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim colName As String

    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set y = Workbooks("Template.xlsm")

    Set ws1 = y.Sheets("Run Results")
    Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Failed")

    With ws1

        Set aCell = .Range("B2:J2").Find(What:=header, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        'If Found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

            col = aCell.Column
            colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)

            lRow = Range(colName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            Set myCol = Range(colName & "2")

            Select Case fType

                Case "Copy"

                    'This is your range
                    Set find_Header = Range(myCol.Address & ":" & colName & lRow).Offset(1, 0)

                End Select

        'If not found
        Else

            MsgBox "Column Not Found"

        End If

    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Say your address is A1:B10. Then `Range(find_Header("Failure Type", "Copy").Address & i)` is `Range("A1:B10" & i)`. If i=`100` then this is `Range("A1:B10100)`. You don't want to concatenate, that is for strings. Perhaps you need the Resize method?

Comment: You need to qualify the calls to `Range` everywhere inside your `With ws1` block. I.e., `lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: @SJR AAAAH! That makes so much sense. Wow, I feel like fool lol. Okay, at least that is one problem down. When I do this: `Set xRg = ws1.Range(find_Header("Failure Type", "Copy"))` I get the error: "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed"

Comment: @Comintern Thank you for the reply. I am a little confused, do you mean I need to do this: `lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` in the function or in the sub wherever I want to use the range?

Comment: I think you'd need `Set xRg = find_Header("Failure Type", "Copy")` as your function already returns a range. Two points though: (1) you need to handle cases where the term is not found (see my earlier answer), (2) you might want to add a sheet parameter to your function. As to Comintern's point, if you don't put a dot in front of your Ranges in a With clause the code will refer to the active sheet.

Comment: @SJR Thank you kindly, I will have a look at this when I return to work tomrrow. :)